# Can we get wifiscanresults repeatedly every second?

Tags: android

I am trying to scan all visible wifi APs using wifimanger class. My question is that my code is working good when the (wifiscan-results) called repeatedly every 5 sec using recursive (Runnable) service. But when the time is reduced to be 1 sec or less, such that I register (wifimanger.statrscan) every 1 sec to receive the (wifiscan-results) every 1 sec, the output give null and gives values only every 4 second at least. Could you tell me why this happens. My aim to scan all visible wifi APs every one second or less, repeatedly, Is this possible?

Runnable function code:

```
public void Running() {     
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv1.setText("counter :   " + time1);
                    time1++;
                    Scan_number++;
                    mwifiManager.startScan();
                    periodic_recieving_wifi_signals();
                    Running();
                }
            }, 1000);}
```

broadcastreciever code:

```
 public void periodic_recieving_wifi_signals() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    } else {
        //flag1 = false;

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                //tv2.setText("Each scan period is   : " + results);
                results = mwifiManager.getScanResults();
                size = results.size();// number of the elements in the list


            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    }}
```

Comment: How long does one scan take? I can't see you being able to repeatedly scan more often than that. Just from _using_ an android phone, it feels like a complete scan takes at least a couple of seconds or so.

Comment: a one scan takes 4 seconds or more. Could you give me a scientific reason about why it takes a couple of seconds in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly **cannot** get a WiFi scan every second ... the process simply takes too long.

I don't know all the technical details, and while some of the specific details may vary according to which version of WiFi you are using, looking at [Wi-Fi / WLAN Channels, Frequencies, Bands & Bandwidths](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/wi-fi/80211-channels-number-frequencies-bandwidth.php) we can see that basic 2.4GHz 802.11 WiFi has 14 channels defined and 5GHz WiFi has 25 channels (not all channels are permitted in all locations).

To perform a scan, the radio in your phone has to tune to each channel in turn to see "what's out there". Seeing what (if anything) is on a particular channel will involve an exchange of messages, and will take a finite amount of time<sup>**1**</sup> (it will have to wait "long enough" to tell the difference between a slow-to-respond device and "nothing there").

As you noted in a comment, if all of this is taking four seconds or so, you won't be able to perform a scan faster than about once every five seconds.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Thanks to [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for supplying some numbers. By default, access points transmit their "*I am here*" beacons every 102.4ms. Thus some *minimum* scan-times are:

- 2.4GHz: 14 x 102.4ms = 1,433ms
- 5GHz: 25 x 102.4ms = 2,560ms

(Both figures may be slightly less in some locations, depending on the number or channels allowed to be used).

In practice, you would want to listen on each channel for longer than 102.4ms, otherwise you run the risk of not-quite-getting-a-beacon as you switch *to* a channel, and then switching *from* that channel just as (or before) the next beacon is sent. There may also be a small delay for the radio to stabilise to each new frequency.

This article: ["*SSID Overhead Calculator*"](http://www.revolutionwifi.net/revolutionwifi/p/ssid-overhead-calculator.html) from the Revolution WiFi website (as well as confirming the 102.4ms figure) also shows the dangers of having too many access-points (APs) and/or too many SSIDs... it doesn't take many of each before the time spent sending out these "beacon" frames takes a significant chunk out of your WiFi throughput.  For example: 4 SSIDs on one AP (or 4 single-SSID APs on the same channel, or 2 double-SSID APs on the same channel) will each use about one-eighth of that channel's airtime just with "I am here" beacons!

Comment: This answer is correct. To add more information: access points transmit their beacons every 102.4 ms. Just to scan the 2.4 GHz channels in the US will take 102.4 * 11 = 1,126.4 ms. For the 5 GHz channels there are 25 channels 102.4 * 25 = 2,560 ms. Add more time for each channel change to stabilize and you are close to the 4 second number. Note: some access points and clients do not support all 25 channels.